# Remove null + empty + duplicate elements in arraylist of string

Tags: java, performance, comparative-review

I am looking for the best and fast way(performance wise) to remove null, empty and duplicate elements in arraylist of string.
This method can be called maximum 700 times and the list can contains around 13 strings maximum.
I have created a test case and I can not get an exact value of the execution time to make the difference between both codes below
If someone has an idea, thanks.

```
//Delete null, empty and duplicate element in sting arrayList
public static void removeNullAndEmptyAndDuplicateElementsInList(List<String> stringList) {
    if (stringList != null && !variablesList.isEmpty() && variablesList.size()>1) {
        for (int x = stringList.size() - 1; x >= 0; x--) {
            if (stringList.get(x) == null || stringList.get(x).isEmpty()) {
                stringList.remove(x);
            } else {
                for (int y = 0; y < x; y++) {
                    if (stringList.get(x).equals(stringList.get(y))) {
                        stringList.remove(x);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

or Java 8

```
public static void removeNullAndEmptyAndDuplicateElementsInList(List<String> stringList) {
        if (stringList != null && !variablesList.isEmpty() && variablesList.size()>1) {
            Set<String> stringListSet = stringList.stream()
                    .filter(var -> (var != null && !var.isEmpty()))
                    .distinct()
                    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new));
            stringList = new ArrayList<String>(stringListSet);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your code is either hypothetical (off-topic) or broken (also off-topic). What are you planning to do with the output? What's your usecase? Do you really need the speed?

Comment: Thanks Pimgd for replying. Yes, I really need the speed

Comment: *"Yes, I really need the speed"* how do you know? Do you have a **prove** that your code it too slow?

Comment: @N.Leroy, there is a bug in the second (Java 8) approach. The call will not have any effect on the passed `stringList` contents, because you _assign_ the resulting `ArrayList` to the reference that exists within the method scope only.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need them in a List in the first place?

Wouldn't it be easier to create it as a Set from the start, and only add elements if they're not null or empty.

That way all your conditions are checked: no null, empty or duplicates (implicit thanks to Set).